# .queue() and .proxy(), animation timing in jQuery

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I'm working on a pseudo plugin (*just really an namespaced initializer on the jQuery object*) and I'm having a bit of trouble with `.proxy()` and `.queue()` (*seemingly two of the most misunderstood methods around*)

Anyways, I thought I had the logic sorted out; the function `$.cb()` takes a map of functions as such:

```
$.cb({
    'show':         function(){ },
    'hide':         function(){ },
    'open':         function(){ },
    'close':        function(){ },
    'beforeUpdate': function(){ },
    'afterUpdate':  function(){ }
});
```

These functions (*should*) contain animation sequences applied to `$(this)`, the context of which has internally, via `.proxy()`, been changed to the respective element(s). They are stored in a `settings` variable, available to all methods of the "plugin".

Internally, some namespaced event handlers, attached via `.live({ })`:

```
// ...
'cb.hide': function(event){
    if(event.isPropagationStopped()){
        return false;
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.proxy(settings.hide, this)();
    $(this).hide();
},
'cb.update': function(event, html){
    if(event.isPropagationStopped()){
        return false;
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.proxy(settings.beforeUpdate, this)();
    $(this).html(html);
    $.proxy(settings.afterUpdate, this)();
},
// ...
```

Anyways, the purpose is that there in inherent functionality brought to the table using this "plugin", but the implementer can pass the function map to opt for different transitional animations.

The **problem**, is that I can't seem to get these functions to queue properly; different ones taking precedence, etc. I've tried mocking around with `.queue()` but I can't seem to get anything right with it:

```
// in cb.update
var $this = $(this);
$(this).queue(function(next){
    $.proxy(settings.beforeUpdate, $this)();
    next();
}).queue(function(next){
    $this.html(html);
    next();
}).queue(function(next){
    $.proxy(settings.afterUpdate, $this)();
}).dequeue();
```

The problem is especially prevalent with the `'cb.update'` event, as the order should be:

- `beforeUpdate` is called (*animation sequence occurs and completes*)
- The element's contents are updated via `.html()`
- `afterUpdate` is called (*animation sequence occurs and completes*)

Whats **actually** happening is:

- The element's contents are updated via `.html()`
- `beforeUpdate` is called (*animation sequence occurs and completes*)
- `afterUpdate` is called (*animation sequence occurs and completes*)

So given the supplied animation is simply `.fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` for `beforeUpdate` and `afterUpdate` respectively, it's updating the contents, then fading out and in.

So, any suggestions on this sort of implementation? How can I ensure the proper ordering of the events/animations? Have I gone a *wildly* stupid route in terms of trying to implement such a feature?